# Installing GCC 13.1.0 on x86_64 Debian

Tags: compiling, gcc

Did anybody here manage to install GCC 13.1.0 on their computer? When I try to build it from source on my 64-bit Debian Linux, I get the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/hwasan.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__ehdr_start' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [Makefile:559: libhwasan.la] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/teo/gcc-objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libsanitizer/hwasan'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:532: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/teo/gcc-objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libsanitizer'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:419: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/teo/gcc-objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libsanitizer'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:22725: all-target-libsanitizer] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/teo/gcc-objdir'
make: *** [Makefile:1090: all] Error 2
```

I configured it with `../gcc-13.1.0/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib`.
My current GCC version is:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-12.2.0/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 12.2.0 (GCC)
```

Since this is a linking error, I suppose my current linker may be relevant. It is:

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.31.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

So, what do you think is the problem and how can I solve it?

The probability that I will manage to install it on Windows is so low it's not even worth trying. Do you agree?

Comment: You seem to be building that with a nonstandard Gcc toolchain installed into /usr/local. It's impossible for us to know whether and in which ways that is broken. Try with a fresh debian installation using the debian GCC!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Why is it more likely that the GCC toolchain I've built myself from source, without modifying the source code, is broken, than that the GCC that ships with Debian, which is heavily modified by people who know next-to-nothing about compilers, is broken?

Comment: Because the debian toolchain works for millions of other people? Asking them, certainly a solid fraction of the GCC developers themselves? And why would you say that the debian GCC maintainers group knows next to nothing about compilers? That seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @MarcusMüller GCC 13.1 is a major release (full of new features, and containing basically no bug-fixes) and it's been released only a few days ago. Don't you think it is far more likely to be some undetected bug in GCC 13.1?

Comment: @MarcusMüller What you are essentially telling me is that I should **downgrade** my GCC to 10.4 (or whichever version comes with Debian) in order to build a new version of GCC. That runs contrary to the typical advice on how to build GCC. It is typically advised that you should build in small increments, that you are less likely to run into trouble if you are using GCC 12.2 to build GCC 13.1 than if you are using GCC 10.4 to build GCC 13.1. And it should be obvious why.

Comment: @FlatAssembler When considering that GCC 13.1 is, as you stated, a new release that has been available for a few days, that what you are experiencing is likely to happen? The fact that you are compiling it with a nonstandard GCC is the first thing that comes up. It's completely within the realm of possibility that it is isn't compatible with the compilation of GCC 13.1. To be sure, you don't have to downgrade anything. If it's Bullseye, then the standard `gcc` and `g++` are already in /usr/bin and if not, they are available from the repos. Start there and see if the same occurs.

Comment: @NasirRiley So, if I understand you correctly, you are telling me that I should `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc` and `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++` and rerun `configure` and `make`?

Comment: @FlatAssembler Eventually but first, you may need to compile mpc`, and `mpfr`. Sometimes it doesn't matter but I've found that it's best to have the latest especially considering that this is the latest `GCC`. `gmp` in Bullseye is actually the latest but `mpfr` and `gmp` are a few minor releases behind. You'll also need to use compiler flags to for the latter two and then finally use compiler flags to specify the location of where the binaries and libraries are for those components. You may run into more errors but that will get you started.

Comment: @NasirRiley Never heard of mpc and mpfr.

Comment: @FlatAssembler Now you have. If you are going to compile GCC, then you'll need to do some research on what is needed and also on compiling in general.

Comment: @NasirRiley Do some research on compilers? I have made a web-app that converts arithmetic expressions to i486-compatible assembly back in high-school ( https://flatassembler.github.io/compiler.html ) and I am developing a compiler that compiles my own programming language to WebAssembly ( https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly.git ). What more research do you think I need to do?

Comment: @FlatAssembler If you didn't need it, then you wouldn't be here inquiring how to compile GCC with a nonstandard compiler chain. You'd use the system compiler and at worst, use one of the 8533685 guides online if an issue comes up. I compiled GCC 13.1 yesterday on my Bullseye machine with no issues by using the system GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to be caused by a bug in ld 2.31.1: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24458.

The bug was fixed in ld 2.32 and a later point release of 2.31 (but not one that seems to have made it into the Debian 10 package repository).

While I have not tried it, a likely workaround is to obtain a newer ld (perhaps building it from source), and then use it for the gcc build (I'm not sure offhand what build flag allows specifying the linker to use, but presumably there is one).

Answer (score 0):

```bash
export CFLAGS="-O2 -fPIC"
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
./configure && make
```

It's right there on the first error line: *"can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC"*

Comment: Tried it, got the same error. Looked a bit above in the invocation that the GNU Make does, GNU Make does pass the `-fPIC` flag, it just appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to install GCC 13 on a Debian based distro I found an article, which when followed with MX-Linux (Debian bookworm base) worked perfectly (config, build and install).

[Installation Tutorial](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2023/07/28/gcc-13-2-debian-bookworm-installation-step-by-step/)